# Find the distance between a plane line and a point

Tags: linear-algebra

$$y = 1, A(1,-2)$$
This is what I have so far.

since I only have y, how do I figure out x for my normal vector ? I guessed .... [0,1]

$\bigg |$ $ ([x1,y1] - [x0,y0] )$ $ \cdot [0,1] \over \sqrt{1} $ $\bigg |$

$\bigg |$ $ ([1,-2] - [x0,y0] )$ $ \cdot [0,1] \over \sqrt{1} $ $\bigg |$

Not sure where to go from there.

Thanks

Comment: "Plane line"?..

Comment: common someone explains why the thumbs down, I tryed to solve it before asking, did some research, used math ml thing, made it as clear as possible the way I understand it. Plane line is because the problem says " La droite planaire" which I translated to plane line...

Comment: I almost don't downvote and even less for calling things this or that way, if that's what you were implying. Anyway, There's an answer to your question donw here already...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean you "only have $\,y"\,$? You have the straight, horizontal line $\,y=1\,$ and the point $\,A(1,-2)\,$ . The distance of these to things is, of course, the absolute value of the difference $\,|-2-1|=3\,$ since clearly the point $\,(1,1)\,$ on the given line is on the same vertical line as $\,A\,$ and is thus on the perpendicular line to $\,y=1\,$ passing through $\,A\,$ ... Draw a diagram!

Answer (score 1):

> Find the distance between a plane line and a point $$y = 1, A(1,-2)$$

> 3

[image]